# Entity Framework 5.0 EntityObject Generator not available in Visual Studio 2012 RC?

Tags: t4, entity-framework-5, visual-studio-2012

Carry over from social.msdn.microsoft.com...

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/4993d0bf-94e8-4d14-aff1-3458b4ad467f?prof=required

**Original Post**

*I try to migrate a project from 2010 EF 4.3.1 (modified EntityObject generator template) up to vs 2012 rc, ef 5.0 rc and .Net 45 rc.
Painfully, my old T4 template doesnt work any longer. Where can I get the correct template to migrate it to EF 5.0 ?
I can compile the old project, but after starting the app I receive an exception with "different scheme detected".*

**My contribution, still unresolved**

The EntityObject code generation template was available in VS 11 Beta on a "clean" machine, so I would imagine it's an upgrade issue/conflict, possibly related to having EF 4.2 June 2011 CTP installed prior (despite uninstalling).

- VS 2012 Repair - did not fix the problem
- VS 2010/2012 RC Uninstall/Reinstall - did not fix the problem
- VS 2012 RC install on a clean machine - don't have time atm

**Screenshots**

[What I'm expecting to see when adding a code generation template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzQ09.png)

[What I see when adding a code generation template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcSc0.png)

[Only DbContext in Extension Gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FM9JE.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We are finishing verifying VSIX versions of the EntityObject and Self-Tracking Entities code-gen templates. These should be available in the Visual Studio Gallery (or the online tab of the "Add code generation item" menu) shortly if verification goes well. I will reply here as soon as they are uploaded.

Comment: Whew that's a relief.  Did I miss it in the release notes?  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Almost two months now and still no news?

Comment: RTM and still no word?  I tried the DbContext template and it was 1.5x slower than the previous EntityObject template.

Comment: Hacked up the EF 4.2 CTP EntityObject code-gen template and it works.  Unfortunately didn't have a copy of VS 11 BETA to pull the more recent version.  Still immensely faster than DbContext...sigh

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the long wait on these ones. The templates are now available on Visual Studio Gallery. See this page for details - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/JJ613116#EntityObject

~Rowan

Comment: Random additional question, why is there a template for websites as well?  Anything particularly important?

Comment: Hey Paul - The following is copied from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/JJ613116...  The "Web Sites" templates (i.e. EF 5.x DbContext Generator for C# Web Sites) are for use in Web Site projects created via File -> New -> Web Site.... These are different from Web Applications, created via File -> New -> Project..., which use the standard templates. We provide separate templates because the item template system in Visual Studio requires them.