# Is MySQL Entity supported in Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 RC?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I installed  [MySQL connector for .Net v6.5](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net) and it is supported by Entity Framework. When I use Visual Studio 2012 and try to add an ADO.NET Entity Data Model, I can't see MySQL. There are just Microsoft SQL Servers. It worked in VS 2010.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914894/entity-framework-5-0-entityobject-generator-not-available-in-visual-studio-2012) said that they are working on it - is there a conclusion?

Comment: That question doesn't have any relation to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connector .NET v6.5.4 available today does not support VS 2012. You can't add a connection to MySQL in the Server Explorer to begin with.

Support will be included in 6.5.5 as per post: [MySQL forum](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,546265,564533#msg-564533)

There is apparently some workarounds and 3rd party ways to get this working but personally I will just wait.

Answer (score 5):

use this mysql connector for vs 2012. once you install it then you have no such error and
mysql server shows in datasource.

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.6.html

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide an update: The 6.5 version of the connector does NOT support VS2012.
But there is a development release of 6.6 that does. 
Go to the following URL and click on the tab "Development Releases" to download it:
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/#downloads

Answer (score 0):

Download "MySQL.Connector.Net.6.5.4.VS2012.vsix" and install it to be able to use MySQL in Visual Studio 2012.

You might need to restart Visual Studio after installing it to see the changes.